# Can't overload Threaded::run from internal class

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, php-extension, php-pthread

[Here's an gist of what I'm attempting](https://gist.github.com/ClosetMonkey/55d179e1205942c1d7b8b4617985e973)

As you can see, it should overload run within pthreads_thread_entry parent, but it doesn't.

```
<?php
$test = new Test();
$test->start();
$test->join();
?>
```

Should print a thread id and sleep 10 seconds, but it doesn't print anything (but `var_dump($test->start())` returns bool true) and it does't sleep. However, directly calling `$test->run();` will work (however likely not within it's own thread - haven't tested)

What gives? How do you overload Threaded::run inside of a custom internal class within pthread ext?